# Containing Story Board Animations in a Custom WPF Window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, animation, window, storyboard

Okay, so here is my problem. I have a custom window with a custom shadow, as well as two translation transform animations. The end results is somewhat like the Window 8 Metro Screen. I.E. A Window in which there are several full window user controls that slide from Left to Right and vice versa. Now the problem is that I do not know how to contain the animations so that the they do not draw over the custom window shadow that I have.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[image: During transition - I want to stop the animation displaying over the shadows]

And here is the window after the transition:
[image: After transition]

Here is the XAML for my window:

```
<Window x:Name="PrimaryWindow"
 x:Class="MainWindow"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Metro_Test"
 Title="MainWindow"
 Height="800"
 Width="1280"
 IsTabStop="False"
 AllowsTransparency="True"
 Background="Transparent"
 BorderBrush="#FF3F3F3F"
 SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
 TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
 TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
 WindowStyle="None"
 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" AllowDrop="True" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:ValueConverter x:Key="NegativeConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="NoChromeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Chrome" Value="0.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Image x:Key="WhiteClose" Source="Images\White\Close.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
    <Image x:Key="WhiteAdd" Source="Images\White\Add.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
    <Image x:Key="WhiteMinus" Source="Images\White\Minus.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
    <Image x:Key="GrayClose" Source="Images\Gray\Close.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
    <Image x:Key="GrayAdd" Source="Images\Gray\Add.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
    <Image x:Key="GrayMinus" Source="Images\Gray\Minus.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="PageViews">
        <x:XData>
            <Views xmlns="">
                <View Title="View1">
                    <Page Source="MainPage.xaml"/>
                </View>
                <View Title="View2">
                    <Page Source="AddReferencePage.xaml"/>
                </View>
                <View Title="View3">
                    <Page Source="ReferenceManagementPage.xaml"/>
                </View>
            </Views>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

    <Storyboard x:Key="SlideLeftToRight"  
                TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                AccelerationRatio=".5"
                DecelerationRatio=".5">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PageViewer" Duration="0:0:0.8" From="{Binding Width, ElementName=PrimaryWindow}" To="0"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderVisual" Duration="0:0:0.8" From="0" To="{Binding Width, ElementName=PrimaryWindow, Converter={StaticResource NegativeConverter}}"/>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="SlideRightToLeft" 
                TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                AccelerationRatio=".5"
                DecelerationRatio=".5">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PageViewer" Duration="0:0:0.8" From="{Binding Width, ElementName=PrimaryWindow, Converter={StaticResource NegativeConverter}}" To="0"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderVisual" Duration="0:0:0.8" From="0" To="{Binding Width, ElementName=PrimaryWindow}"/>
    </Storyboard>

    <VisualBrush x:Key="VisualBrush1" Visual="{Binding ElementName=PageViewer}"/>

</Window.Resources>

<Border
    x:Name="m_edgeBorder"
    Margin="14"
    Background="White">

    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect
        Opacity="0.999"
        BlurRadius="14"
        ShadowDepth="0"/>
    </Border.Effect>

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">

        <Rectangle
            x:Name="TitleBar"
            Height="28"
            Fill="Blue"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            AllowDrop="False"
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="FormMouseDown"
            PreviewMouseMove="FormMouseMove"/>

        <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="HandleCloseClick" MouseEnter="HandleMouseEnter" MouseLeave="HandleMouseLeave" ClickMode="Release" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="500,2,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Height="24">
            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="GrayClose"/>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="MaximiseButton" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="HandleMaximiseClick" MouseEnter="HandleMouseEnter" MouseLeave="HandleMouseLeave" ClickMode="Release" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="500,2,28,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Height="24">
            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="GrayAdd"/>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="MinimiseButton" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="HandleMinimiseClick" MouseEnter="HandleMouseEnter" MouseLeave="HandleMouseLeave" ClickMode="Release" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="500,2,54,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Height="24">
            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="GrayMinus"/>
        </Button>

        <TextBlock Text="Metro Form" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe Light" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>

        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,28,0,0">
                <ListBox x:Name="ViewList" Height="20" Width="300" SelectedIndex="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PageViews}, XPath=Views/View}"
                DisplayMemberPath="@Title"                    
                SelectionChanged="ChangedSlideSelection">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                <Border x:Name="BorderVisual" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RectangleVisual"/>
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                </Border>

                <ItemsControl x:Name="PageViewer" DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=ViewList}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Page}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Frame x:Name="frame" Source="{Binding XPath=@Source}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
</Window>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `Border` or a `Grid` or some other container as the container of the whole thing (right below the Window before any other element), with the needed `Margin`, and in your animations reference this element, instead of the `Window`.

Edit:

Should be something like:

```
<Window>
   <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Margin="10,0,10,0"> <!-- Or add more margin if needed -->
      ....
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
      ....
    </Grid
</Window>
```

Comment: As in right after Window.Resources? I tried this and it did not work, the animation still spreads to the Window's border.

Comment: But did you change the animations to reference the new border instead? and also did you add a Margin to this border?

Comment: How do I reference the animations to the new object? EDIT: Also, when I added the grid, it showed in the Designer (?) as being snapped to the sides of the actual window (minus the border)

Comment: Do not use the designer. Make sure you add the needed margin on each side so that your actual content does not exceed the grid. What I mean by referencing the grid on the animations is, give a name to the Grid change the `{Binding Width, ElementName=PrimaryWindow}` to `{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TheGrid}`

Comment: Okay, I did that, and am now referencing the grid that contains the ItemControl. If I add margins, all it does is cause the ItemControl to become smaller, and the animation still protrudes out into the border. I'll keep googling! Also, I did use ActualWidth.

Comment: It says I am unable to put the storyboard in the Grid due to it not being a dictionary. Also, the animations are called like this:
`If PreviousSelection < ViewList.SelectedIndex Then
            PageViewer.BeginStoryboard(DirectCast(Me.Resources("SlideLeftToRight"), Storyboard))
        Else
            PageViewer.BeginStoryboard(DirectCast(Me.Resources("SlideRightToLeft"), Storyboard))
        End If`

Comment: Okay, Added the Storyboard to the Grid.Resources, however the problem still persists (Yes, I also changed the calling event to Grid.Resources)

Comment: Still not sure how you are suggesting to place the DoubleAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it! All I had to do was set the Grid's ClipToBounds property to true! Thanks to HighCore for putting me on the right track! If anyone experiences this problem and can't solve it, let me know!